# Is using do until best for offsetting a value?

Tags: excel, vba

What this is supposed to do: When a user enters a value for ttxt on a userform and clicks on the button 'add' it will first check if the value is blank, and if it is it will enter the input value of the user-- if its not empty, it will go 2 columns over to the right and enter the value there. This will keep adding the value to the right once every button click. I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
'Starts on column G1
Range("G1").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select 

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ttxt.Value
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
ActiveCell.Value = Me.ttxt
Else
'Offsets to the right 2 columns to enter another value if previous value is 
'not empty.
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.ttxt
End If
Loop
Me.ttxt = ""
```

See below

```
Private Sub addbtn_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Dim r As Range
Set t = Range("F1").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
Set r = Range("G1").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
Do Until r.Value = "" And t.Value = ""
Set r = r.Offset(, 2) 'Moves over 2 columns
Set t = t.Offset(, 2) 'Moves over 2 columns
Loop
'Inputs values
r.Value = Me.ttxt
t.Value = Me.atxt & ", " & Me.xtxt
With Me.ListBox1
.AddItem
.List(i, 0) = Me.ttxt
.List(0, i) = Me.atxt & ", " & Me.xtxt
i = i + 1
End With
'Clears out userform
Me.ttxt = ""
Me.atxt = ""
Me.xtxt = ""
End Sub
```

So this is the entire code for the add click button. So this code as you know adds the user input values into the columns like its supposed to. I have a listbox on the userform as well. Whenever a person adds the values to the sheet I want the values to be placed into the listbox as well. The current code adds the first value, and any value after that it just replaces the first value in the listbox. Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to say.

I want the values to keep being added down the list whenever I add them as it does on the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub AlternateColumnsEmpty()
'Starts on column G1
  Dim r As Range
  Set r = Range("G3")
  If r.Value = "" Then
    r.Value = Me.ttxt
  Else
    Cells(r.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 2).Value = Me.ttxt
  End If
  Me.ttxt = ""
End Sub

Sub AlternateColumnsHaveData()
'Starts on column G1
  Dim r As Range
  Set r = Range("G3")
  Do Until r.Value = ""
    Set r = r.Offset(, 2)
  Loop
  r.Value = Me.ttxt
  Me.ttxt = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Understood regarding the cells selecting. Aside from that, this works, but it only places the value into another column once. I want it to keep offsetting 2 columns to the right whenever the user enters a value if the current value is not empty. So i pretty much want it to check the columns of row 3, if you understand what I mean. So if the value is placed in A1, I need the code to check if that's empty, and if its not, move to C1 and place the value there. If A1 and C1 are not empty, then I need it to add the value to E1 and so on.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand.  Here's what I'm getting from your question: 1 - start on G3, if empty store value here, else I3 (offset 0,2). 2 - next entry would look at G4, if empty store value here, else I4.. and so on.  Is this not what you want to happen?

Comment: So the code starts on G3. If G3 is not empty, I want the value to be stored in I3. If G3 and I3 are not empty, I want the value to be stored on K3, and so on. Currently the code is focused on G3 and I3 and thats it. I want it to keep offsetting to different columns if the previous cells are not empty. @DaveU

Comment: Oh, I see.  So before proceeding, might there be data in the alternate columns (H,J,L,etc), or can we assume they'll always be empty?

Comment: I've updated my answer with two possibilities, use the one that works for your situation.

Comment: Yes exactly. If I ever need to add a new value to the list it will be placed in the next empty column. So it has to check the other columns first if the cells are empty or not. I will check out the code right now. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, one more thing @DaveU. Please take a look at my edited question for the additem to the listbox. It keeps replacing the previous value on the listbox.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, need to see the additem code.

Comment: I edited the question with more detail. Please see above.

Comment: Replace `.List(i, 0) = Me.ttxt` and `.List(0, i) = Me.atxt & ", " & Me.xtxt` with this: `.List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = Me.ttxt` and `.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Me.atxt & ", " & Me.xtxt`

Comment: Great, can you check this off as answered?  Thanks.